# Pass and return custom array object in ibatis and oracle in java

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis

I've looked around for a good example of this, but I haven't run into one yet.  I want to pass a custom string array from java to oracle and back, using the IBATIS framework.  Does anyone have a good link to an example?  I'm calling stored procs from IBATIS.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by a *custom* string array, is this somehow different from String[] ?

Answer (score 2):

You've got to start with a custom instance of `TypeHandler`.  We'd prefer to implement the simpler `TypeHandlerCallback`, but in this scenario we need access to the underlying `Connection`.

```
public class ArrayTypeHandler implements TypeHandler {

    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object param, String jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        if (param == null) {
            ps.setNull(i, Types.ARRAY);
        } else {
            Connection conn = ps.getConnection();
            Array loc = conn.createArrayOf("myArrayType", (Object[]) param);
            ps.setArray(i, loc);
        }
    }

    public Object getResult(CallableStatement statement, int i)
            throws SQLException {
        return statement.getArray(i).getArray();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, to wire it up in the iBATIS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">

<sqlMap namespace="arrayTest">

    <parameterMap id="storedprocParams" class="map">
        <parameter property="result" mode="OUT" jdbcType="ARRAY" typeHandler="ArrayTypeHandler"/>
        <parameter property="argument" mode="IN" jdbcType="ARRAY" typeHandler="ArrayTypeHandler"/>
    </parameterMap>

    <procedure id="storedproc" parameterMap="arrayTest.storedprocParams">
        {? = call My_Array_Function( ? )}
    </procedure>

</sqlMap>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was a good starting point - I had to get the native connection from RAD, add a descriptor which described my custom array, and make sure that the object in the database was accessible.  See what I did in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

bsanders gave me a good starting point - here's what I had to do to make it work within the RAD environment (websphere 6.2).

```
public Object getResult(CallableStatement statement, int i) throws SQLException {
    return statement.getArray(i).getArray(); //getting null pointer exception here
}

public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object param, String jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    if (param == null) {
        ps.setNull(i, Types.ARRAY);

    } else {
        String[] a = (String[]) param;
        //ARRAY aOracle = ARRAY.toARRAY(a, (OracleConnection)ps.getConnection());

        //com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection
        w = (com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection)ps.getConnection());

        //com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject x;
        Connection nativeConnection = Connection)WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection((WSJdbcConnection)ps.getConnection());

        ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("F2_LIST", nativeConnection);
        ARRAY dataArray = new ARRAY(descriptor, nativeConnection, a);
        ps.setArray(i, dataArray);
    }
}
```

Notice the nativeConnection I had to get, the descriptor I had to make, and so on.  However, while I can pass things into the database as an array of Strings, I haven't been able to figure out why I'm not getting anything back.  My OUT parameter (the getResult(CallableStatement statment, int i)  is throwing a null pointer exception, even though I'm setting the out parameter in the plsql in the database.

```
--stored procedure to take a | delimited ids
   PROCEDURE array_test (argument IN f2_list, result OUT f2_list) 
   AS
      l_procname_v   VARCHAR2 (50)                 := 'array_test';
      l_param_list   VARCHAR2 (2000)
                   := l_procname_v || ' param_values: p_string: ';

      p_status_n     NUMBER;
      p_message_v    VARCHAR2 (2000);
      ret_list f2_list := new f2_list();
      l_count_v varchar2(200);
   BEGIN

      l_count_v := argument.COUNT;
      for x in 1..argument.count
      LOOP
          pkg_az_common_util.az_debug (package_nm,
                                   l_procname_v,
                                   pkg_az_data_type_def.debug_num,
                                   argument(x)
                                  );
      end loop;

      pkg_az_common_util.az_debug (package_nm,
                                   l_procname_v,
                                   pkg_az_data_type_def.debug_num,
                                   l_count_v
                                  );
      ret_list.extend();
      ret_list(1) := 'W';
      ret_list.extend();
      ret_list(2) := 'X';
      ret_list.extend();
      ret_list(3) := 'Y';
      ret_list.extend();
      ret_list(4) := 'Z';

      result := ret_list;


   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         p_status_n := pkg_az_common_util.get_error_code;
         p_message_v :=
               TO_CHAR (p_status_n)
            || '|'
            || 'Oracle Internal Exception('
            || l_procname_v
            || ')'
            || '|'
            || TO_CHAR (SQLCODE)
            || '|'
            || SQLERRM
            || l_param_list;
         standard_pkg.log_error (package_nm,
                                 l_procname_v,
                                 SQLCODE,
                                 p_message_v
                                );

         IF p_status_n = 1
         THEN
            RAISE;
         END IF;
   END array_test;
```

Here is how I'm accessing it:

```
Map queryParamsTest = new HashMap();

        String[] testArray = {"A", "B", "C"};

        queryParamsTest.put("argument", testArray);



        DaoUtils.executeQuery(super.getSqlMapClientTemplate(),
                "arrayTest", queryParamsTest, queryParamsTest
                .toString());  //just executes query


        String[] resultArray = (String[])queryParamsTest.get("result");

        for(int x = 0; x< resultArray.length; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Result: " + resultArray[x]);
        }



<parameterMap id="storedprocParams" class="map">        
        <parameter property="argument" mode="IN" jdbcType="ARRAY" typeHandler="ArrayTypeHandler"/>    
        <parameter property="result" mode="OUT" jdbcType="ARRAY" typeHandler="ArrayTypeHandler"/>        
    </parameterMap>    
    <procedure id="arrayTest" parameterMap="storedprocParams">        
        {call pkg_az_basic_dev.array_test(?, ? )}    
    </procedure>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, guys in company found out the **solution**: you need to have implemented getResult method(s) in your typeHandler and provided additional attribute jdbcTypeName=ORACLE_REAL_ARRAY_TYPE in your mapper

Comment: i have noticed the ARRAY type is not supported in the batis documentation, i found that desinformative

Answer (score 0):

Try using `statement.getObject(i)` and then casting to an array.