# Passing a "table of varchar2(255)" input parameter to an Oracle stored procedure from c# via Ibatis

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, ibatis

I'm using Ibatis from c#. In Oracle I have a global type definition

```
create or replace type charArray is table of varchar2(255);
```

I'm using this type as an input parameter in a stored procedure. Typically it should contain a couple of thousand strings, each of them having length 25-30.

This procedure searches these values in a specified column of a table and returns the result set in a type defined in a TYPES package as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PACKAGE TYPES AS
type cursorType is ref cursor;
END;
```

The header of my stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE psearch (
    P_RESULTSET OUT  TYPES.cursorType,
        P_SEARCHEDSTRINGS in charArray
)
```

I'd like to define a parameterMap in my sqlmap to call this stored procedure from c# via Ibatis.

My parameterMap should look like this:

```
<parameterMaps>
    <parameterMap id="parmap" class="Hashtable">
        <parameter property="P_RESULTSET" mode="OUT" column="P_RESULTSET" dbType="RefCursor"/>
        <parameter property="P_SEARCHEDSTRINGS " mode="IN" column="P_SEARCHEDSTRINGS " dbType="????"/>
    </parameterMap>
</parameterMaps>
```

The first (output) parameter works fine (I've tested it in a one-parameter test version of this procedure, and got the desired result by Mapper.Instance().QueryForList()). But I can't find out the dbType of the second (the input) parameter.

I tried already "charArray", "table", "varchar2", "varhcar2[]" , but none of them worked.

Any idea?

Comment: mybatis or ibatis?
accoding to [this](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s07.html), array-type parameters are not supported. consider looking into oracle bulk insert, if that is an option.

Comment: This is IBatis.DataMapper.1.6.2 and IBatis.DataAccess.1.9.2. It's true, that I don't see here arrays (except byte[]), but I also don't see RefCursor, still it works.

Comment: you are right, that documentation is obviously outdated, and I found the versioning very confusing too, since sources moved from github to google code.
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136034/pass-and-return-custom-array-object-in-ibatis-and-oracle-in-java), it is solved in java. A c# solution is not given, but it might just be a matter of translation

Comment: Finally, I've found a [workaround](http://twit88.com/blog/2008/03/14/ibatis-support-for-arrays-or-list-parameters-in-with-sql-in-keyword/ ) for my problem. For applying this, I had to replace my stored procedure to a view, and due to the limitation of 1000 in the in () list, I had to partition my query. It works fine.

Comment: glad to hear that you found a solution. If you need to overcome the limit of 1000 items in the () list, make a second two-column table sessionid/string, bulk-insert your list of strings along with a unique sessionid, then call the procedure with the sessionid as a parameter and using an INNER JOIN on that other table with the sessionid in the WHERE clause.