# How to convert integer[] into List<Integer> directly when mapping with JAVA object in myBatis

Tags: java, mybatis, postgresql-9.3

I'm using `PostgreSQL`. One of my table fields is an array:

```
"day_of_month" int[] DEFAULT NULL
```

But my domain object for this table is `List<Integer>`. I want to fetch the attribute value in of the attribute in POJO with type `:List<Integer>` using `MyBAtis` query API.

Is there any automatic way to do this, is there anything provided by `Postgresql` to directly convert it into `List<Integer>`, wanted to avoid extra processing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use custom TypeHandler, [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137693/7076047).

You are specifically interested in *getResult* method,  `statement.getArray(i).getArray()` will return an *Object[]*. Just put it into a List (or anything you want): `Arrays.asList()` and return it.
By the way, don't forget null check to avoid NPE.

Of course, reference it in your *resultMap* with attribute `typeHandler="type.handler.full.qualified.name"`

Comment: yeah...this is one of the alternatives...but I wanted something in postgresql query itself.

Comment: yeah, that's what you asked. But I wonder what is the purpose?
You seem to use a "cast"-like syntax, but it could only work for input.
What you want would involve Postgres to "know" what is a java List, but why should it?
The jdbc driver provides a resultSet to fetch results as "simple" java types.
Mybatis is another layer over that to map to more complex structures such as List.