# Sending a list of java objects to an SQL stored procedure via mybatis?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, mybatis

I've asked this question before - didn't really end up with a working solution, and that might have been somewhat my own problem for not really knowing at the time, what the hell I wanted to do.

Please don't flag this as a duplicate, as I intend including better information on it.

Here is my mapper xml :

```
<select id="deleteItems" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    exec [dbo].[PR_ItemsForDeletion_Delete]
</select>
```

Now, we can ignore the result map here I believe - because I am not concerned with what I am getting back (yet!)

Now, see that stored procedure? I didn't write it - and I also don't have access to the code for that - but I do know for a fact that it works.

The stored procedure takes a list of items. I need to pass in the following :

```
List<CustomDeletableObject>
```

Trusting that the sproc works, and with the mapper I just want to execute that mapping XML - and pass a list to it, but I have ABSOLUTELY no idea where to begin with that.

Massive thankyou in advance, I have been banging my head against this one for hours now.

The custom deletable object type contains two properties :

private long id - which is just an id we use. private Sting token - the data we are actually storing.

the Stored procedure, I don't have access to the query itself - but essentially what it does, is deletes every item in a table which has a match to an item in the list we want to provide to it via myBatis.

This is how I am planning to call the mapper...

```
@Override 
public boolean deleteItems(List<CustomDeletableObject> tokens){

    // This method handles the deletion.
    jobMapper.deleteItems();

    return false;
}
```

Here is the stored procedure I am trying to use : In the interest of security, the table names have been replaced with nonsense TABLE tags.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_ItemsForDeletion_Delete]
    @pTokenList dbo.UDT_TokenDeletion READONLY
AS

BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY    
        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @pTokenList)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO <TABLE> (Token)
                SELECT
                    Token
                FROM @pTokenList tl
                WHERE NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 1
                    FROM <TABLE> tp
                    WHERE tp.Token = tl.Token
                )
            END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    ;THROW
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend `BaseTypeHandler` and specially `setNonNullParameter` method. [Here is example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136034/7076047), not so bad, but look up for more.

It seems what you need is (close to) [Table-Valued Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/mt651781(v=sql.110).aspx#Anchor_5)

This is is driver specific JDBC code to put in the type handler method.

Reference the type handler in the parameter binding in call.

```
<delete id="deleteItems">
    exec dbo.PR_ItemsForDeletion_Delete #{list, typeHandler=com.fully.qualified.name.TokenListTypeHandler}
</delete>
```

Semantically the intention is deleting, better use the keyword even though there is no technical impact. no need for result map if there is no result to map.

Comment: Thanks for the information - So there is no REAL way to pass an actual list over to the stored procedure? I need to pass an array over?

Comment: The 1st example is about writing a type handler for Oracle Array, this is only to illustrate how to implement, don't focus on that, generalize. In your case, you will likely build SQLServerDataTable (2nd link) from the list, copy/paste in your type handler implementation, then barely few  more adaptations could be enough.

Comment: Thanks - I will investigate. This is the hardest thing ever to get working. I have been working on it for 14 weeks now. :(