# Pass Array of POJO items to a stored procedure using mybatis?

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, mybatis

I have the following java class :

```
public class item implements Serializable {    

    private long id;
    private String name;    

    public long getUuid() {
        return id;
    }    

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }    

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }    

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

Lets assume I have an array of these - and I have a stored procedure which can iterate over a collection - known as "@pItemsToProcess".

What do I need to do to make my stored procedure take this array?

So I need to write some sort of type handler? If so, would it be for the array? The "item" class? Both?

I've seen other users ask similar questions to this - but there doesn't seem to be a working solution on any of the questions.

I am also open to maybe having the DB team change the stored procedure to work with one item at a time, and calling the proc with each item if that would be easier? Because this proc would only get called once a day, with around 20 items, it is not latency sensitive, and we are not worried about load.

EDITS BELOW THIS LINE! ----------

Database type is an SQL server.

Comment: Solutions exist, they indeed rely on type handler, but the implementation is DB vendor driver specific, would you mind add this information in the question?

Comment: Added the information :)

Answer (score 0):

In case, DB is SQL server, I have already answered pretty much the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43091870/7076047).

**EDIT**:

The anchor the link [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters#Anchor_5) does not seem to work, the interesting snippet is in chapter **Passing a Table-Valued Parameter as a SQLServerDataTable Object**.

The type handler is a kind of qualifier for parameters. It is used for every parameter but usually unspecified since Mybatis resolves the type handler to use matching parameter type according to a default mapping type => typeHandler. TypeHandler is usually specified to use a custom type handler to handle a complex type of implement a specific behavior.

In the answer I reference, I do not exactly give the solution to OP's situation, but rather all pieces to put together:

The [Type handler example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136034/pass-and-return-custom-array-object-in-ibatis-and-oracle-in-java) is about passing a SQL ARRAY to Oracle DB. Then solution is about adapting that to pass SQL-Server **Table-Valued Parameter** instead.

Comment: I saw this solution yesterday when I was searching - yes - the DB is a SQL server - and I can fully make sense of the xml section where you hit the procedure, and hand it the list - but what I don't get is how to write a type handler for this? Do I write it for a List? Do I write it for the "item" class? Maybe I do it for both?

Comment: am I missing something in the example on that other person's question? I don't see how the typehandler stuff works at all.